# Howto host Vimeo videos on Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, video-streaming, vimeo

How do I get [Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/introduction-to-mobile-development) mobile app to host  [vimeo](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries) video playback? While I found how to [play video in Xamarin](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2017/03/16/playing-media-with-xamarin-forms/), I cannot see how to do this for Vimeo?

Answer (score 4):

ill expand on how i've done this for a xamarin forms app.

ie. video url: https://vimeo.com/135727591

use the following to get the config info

https://player.vimeo.com/video/{VideoId}/config

so take video id and get the config using the following:

https://player.vimeo.com/video/135727591/config

now parse the config file from the json received

Answer (score 2):

you need to de-code the initial url to pull the real path the the mp4 file.