# Xamarin forms: Webview for playing video is not working in iPhone?

Tags: video, xamarin.forms, webview

I am using `Webview` for playing video and audio and it is working fine on android and iPhone simulators. But on the real iPhone, video playing is not working fine.

For playing the video on the iPhone, I need to tap the video play button multiple times. After that also it takes a long time to play the video. Another important thing is my video links have no video format(.mp4,.mkv).

**XAML**

```
<WebView 
    x:Name="web_view"
    HeightRequest="200"
    WidthRequest="200"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

**XAML.cs**

```
web_view.Source = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/303543322";
```

I tried `Plugin.MediaManager.Forms`, but it needs video format(.mp4,.mkv) in the link, otherwise it will not work. So is there any way to fix this issue in `webview` itself or should I go for any other player(video and audio) which supports playing video without video format?

Comment: This is an existing issue because of video policy in iOS ,check https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/issues/199 .

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51023692/4739420

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT  Is there any way to fix this issue? My client always reporting this as an issue. He is telling that, needs to tap multiple times for playing video. Also, there is a threat from Appstore: ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage-Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView API. So is there any other way to play video in UI other than webview without the video format in the video link? But it is working fine on android and ios simulators.

Comment: After iOS 13.0 , you would better use `WKWebView`  instead of `UIWebView` . Otherwise you might be rejected by App Store if you want to upload your app  .

Comment: You can download the video to local firstly , then use the plugin https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rox.Xamarin.Video/

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Actually my problem was not the autoplay feature of the video. When I tap to play video, it is not getting played. Video play starts only after some time. Today I update my iPhone to 13.3, after that when I check I didn't see this problem. Video is playing within 2,3 seconds.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Do you know why this is happening? Please post about this as your answer, I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Also I tried 'WKWebView', but getting below error: The type 'WKWebView' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. Please include any fixfor this in your answer.

Comment: WKWebView is what you need to use, however, it exists only in IOS native, so you will need to create a custom renderer to make it work. I had several issues with IOS web view (for example the dictation was not working) and they all were solved after changing the component for WKWebView. I hope this helps.

Comment: @SergioAMG Can you post an answer with a sample custom render?

Comment: Your issue maybe caused by other code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, create a new class inherited from WebView in your PCL. And define a bindable property pointing what url should be loaded on iOS.

```
public class MyWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Url",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(MyWebView),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Url
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

The custom renderer for this class on iOS:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyWebView, WKWebView>
    {
        WKWebView _wkWebView;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                _wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                SetNativeControl(_wkWebView);
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Url)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For Android

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                var customWebView = Element as MyWebView;
                Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;

                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;    
                Control.LoadUrl(customWebView.Url);          
            }

        }
    }
}
```

At last you can use this custom control in the PCL's page, here is the usage:

```
<StackLayout>
    <local:MyWebView Url="https://www.microsoft.com" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Working fine in android, but on IOS getting exception.https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k-VP2BXBw2rztO5aMKfX4zCOoznCwRLH

Comment: Post your sample .

Comment: Sample project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qc4-jOLUk1NzVk0FAK0ZPMBA5_DnIPYb

Comment: Set the Url="xxx" instead of Source

Comment: It is working fine in the sample project, but when I do the same in my main project, getting the above exception.

Comment: Delete the bin and obj , then clean and rebuild it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204341/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).